# past simple or past perfect with an if sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

I would not worry if the parcel **was sent** or **had been** sent surface , but you told me it had been sent airmail

I think the first one is very close to this "if I was rich , I would be happy". BUT as the parcel has already been sent and the action is completed,  the "had been"may be a better choice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the past simple even for specific actions that are complete. You can use the past simple in half of a sentence, and past perfect or present perfect in the other half. You can mix them up, as long as it works *semantically*, and as long as each use is correct in and of itself.

A lot of the time, there's more than one verb structure/form (or 'tense', in common parlance) that can be used in a given situation. Simple forms can often be used where a perfect or progressive aspect can be used. Sometimes only one is natural even though multiple ways of doing it are valid, and you just have to learn those by experience.